# How do you print strings but whenever the user types a specific character it overlaps on whatever is happening and executes the other code in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, input, sleep

Im trying to make something like:

```
import time
if Action == 1:
  while True:
    money += 5
    time.sleep(5)
```

and:

```
Action = input('>')
if Action = 2:
  print('You now have $' + str(money) + '!')
```

so that in the background variable money keeps going up 5 every 5 seconds and whenever the user types in '2' it shows how much the variable money has.

ex.

background:

money = 5

5 secs

money = 10

5 secs

money = 15

3 secs

user: 2

You now have $15!

2 secs

money = 20

Comment: try with multi-threading maybe?

Comment: idk how to thread and all tutorials ive searched up on threading i couldnt understand

Answer (score 1):

Fast code (python 3.6):

```
import _thread
import time

scope = [dict(action=1, money=0)]
# Define a function for the thread
def money_handler ():
    while True:
        if scope[0]["action"] == 1:
            scope[0]["money"] += 5
        if scope[0]["action"] == 2:
            scope[0]["money"] += 10
        time.sleep(5)
        print(scope[0]["money"], scope[0]["action"])
def action_handler():
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        scope[0]["action"] = 2 if scope[0]["action"] == 1 else 1

# Create two threads as follows
_thread.start_new_thread(money_handler, ())
_thread.start_new_thread(action_handler, ())
```

Think about that as 2 separate program flows that interact only with `scope` variable

Comment: So, upon running both functions, they execute at the exact same time instead of one after the other? Cool! (P.S. Also, do the functions have to include _handler in them or are they just your preference?)(P.P.S. What are scopes?)

Comment: @AlexTerm _handler is not mandatory for function name. Name them how you wish. Scope, in this case is a memory space that can be accessed by 2 separate threads. Also, in this case, you can rename scope to employees or workers or any relevant name.